# SharePoint API BreakRoleBasedInheritance on Folder doesn't seem to work

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, flow

EDIT: this just started working and I'm not sure what I did. I will update if I figure it out

I am trying to do custom access control on folders under Documents on one of my sites.

Using the API I `POST` to `_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents%252F[FOLDER]')/ListItemAllFields/breakRoleInheritance(false)`. I get back `OK` with `{"d": {"BreakRoleInheritance": null}}` in the body.

According to the documentation this should remove all permissions on my folder and add one for the user making the API call. But this is not happening. If I then try to use the API to remove the permissions I don't want on that folder, they seem to be still inherited and get removed from the parent as well.

I am on Microsoft 365 and I'm authenticating with user with SharePoint Admin privileges.

Comment: Where are you writing this code? on classic experience page/in SPFx/Power automate flow or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm writing the BreakRoleInheritance part it in PowerAutomate

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the folder relative URL in below format:

```
/sites/<site-name>/<document-library>/<folder-name>
```

For Example:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SPConnect/FlowLibrary/My Documents')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(false)
```

**Update from comments**:

You can break permission inheritance using Power Automate like:

[image]

**Output**:

Deleted all inherited permissions:

[image]

Comment: You can also do it easily using SP PnP JS. For more information, check [documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/security/).

Comment: is this getting a different object than what I have? When I passed incorrect path I got back an error, not OK. So I assume the path I'm using isn't an issue. But I'll try

Comment: Check updated answer for Power automate action configuration & output screenshots.

Comment: thank you. It started working, but without me changing the relative URL. Not sure what the initial issue was. I'm still not sure why you think changing the URL would change the result if there was no initial error. Getting the object with the initial URL like `Documents/Folder` gave me back the correct folder object.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! If you are getting the correct object using the path you are already using then it's fine, you can use that also. Normally I use the path with complete relative URL which works for me.

Comment: your suggestion did not solve the issue. I appreciate your help and the time you spent, but I can't accept your answer - it would be misleading

Comment: thank you. The issue turned out to be that the folder I had trouble with already had unique permissions. I didn't know how to check that properly and made assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be user error. The folder I was trying to break inheritance on already had unique permissions. I didn't realize it because they were identical to the permissions of the parent. Once I restored the inheritance, `breakRoleInheritance` worked properly.